# Naming convention in Collections: why are some lowercase and others CapWords?

Tags: python

Why the mixture of lowercase and UpperCamelCase?

```
namedtuple
deque   
Counter 
OrderedDict
defaultdict
```

Why `collections` instead of `Collections`?

I sometimes do this for example:

```
from collections import default_dict
```

by mistake. What rule of thumb can I use to avoid such mistakes in the future?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The collections module follows the [PEP 8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions):

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.

This is why it's `collections`

---

> Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.

This is why it's `Counter` and `OrderedDict`, because they are both classes:

```
>>> collections.Counter
<class 'collections.Counter'>
>>> collections.OrderedDict
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

---

`namedtuple` is a function, so it does not follow the style guide mentioned above. `deque` and `defaultdict`s are types, so they also do not:

```
>>> collections.deque
<type 'collections.deque'>
>>> collections.namedtuple
<function namedtuple at 0x10070f140>
>>> collections.defaultdict
<type 'collections.defaultdict'>
```

---

Note: With Python 3.5, defaultdict and deque are now classes too:

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter
<class 'collections.Counter'>
>>> collections.OrderedDict
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
>>> collections.defaultdict
<class 'collections.defaultdict'>
>>> collections.deque
<class 'collections.deque'>
```

I assume they kept `defaultdict` and `deque` lowercase for backwards compatibility. I would not imagine they'd make such a drastic name change for the sake of a style guide.

Comment: Now that classes and types are supposed to be unified, the difference between CamelCase for Python classes and lowercase for C types is frustratingly awkward.

Comment: Why different styles for types and classes? Should I care about the fact that a Counter is a class and a defaultdict is a type when I use them? In other words, until now I haven't cared about the fact that defaultdict is a type rather than a class. Should I care?

Comment: @Baz I myself wouldn't care. They are similar in some cases, but then again, you and I are different people. Why different styles for types and classes? Well that I don't know. PEP 8 doesn't seem to cover types.

Comment: @Baz: Before type/class unification, the difference used to be really important. Now that type/class unification has been a thing for 16 years, the differences are minor, and the different naming conventions are just an annoying historical relic.

Comment: But they could have added aliases `DefaultDict` and `Deque` for consistency.