# Why is OrderedDict named in camel case while defaultdict is lower case?

Tags: python

Looking at the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/collections/), it seems the only "reason" is that `OrderedDict` is written in Python, while `defaultdict` is in C. But it seems this is changing as Python 3.5 should have a cOrderedDict (see [Python Bugs](http://bugs.python.org/issue16991)), which highlights how bad my only explanation actually is.

Can anyone provide a better explanation? I hope *there is* a better reason.

**Edit**: 
The [alleged duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953681/naming-convention-in-collections-why-are-some-lowercase-and-others-capwords) answer is OK for Python 2.7, not for Python 3 where the class/type distinction is gone. `OrderedDict` and `defaultdict` are both considered classes by the interpreter itself:

```
>>> collections.defaultdict
<class 'collections.defaultdict'> 
>>> collections.OrderedDict
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

Comment: "Now that classes and types are supposed to be unified, the difference between CamelCase for Python classes and lowercase for C types is frustratingly awkward." - user2357112, from a comment in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Addressing your "this is changing" point: that's not how python 3 does c implementations.  For example py3, you do `import pickle` and this delegates to `import _pickle` - the c implementation - if available.

Comment: Thanks, @roippi, I was referring to the patches in <http://bugs.python.org/issue16991> which are called `cOrderedDict`. The fact that both the C and the Python versions will be imported through the same name is irrelevant. The naming conventions for `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` still do won't match.

Answer (score 28):

Based on what I can find on the python-dev archives, this is just a case of the devs not following their own guidelines.

Guido actually suggested  [renaming `defaultdict` to `DefaultDict`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-March/086646.html) to fix this inconsistency during the discussion of the PEP that introduced `OrderedDict`:

> Anyway, it seems the collections module in particular is already
>   internally inconsistent -- `NamedTuple` vs. `defaultdict`. In a sense
>   defaultdict is the odd one out here, since these are things you import
>   from some module, they're not built-in. Maybe it should be renamed to
>   `NamedDict`?

Note that `NamedDict` is a typo, [he meant `DefaultDict`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-March/086644.html):

> > I suppose you mean "DefaultDict".
>
> Yes, I've been distracted. :-(

I'm not sure why this change (and similar changes for other modules, eg `socket.socket`, `datetime.datetime`) was never made, since Guido supported doing it.

Ironically, [it was Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061169.html) (or maybe Alex Martelli) who came up with the name `defaultdict`, despite the fact that they were basing it on an internal class Google was using called `DefaultDict`:

> Google has an internal data type called a `DefaultDict` which gets
>   passed a default value upon construction. Its `__getitem__` method,
>   instead of raising `KeyError`, inserts a shallow copy (!) of the given
>   default value into the dict when the value is not found.
>
> ...snip...
>
> Over lunch with Alex Martelli, he proposed that a subclass of dict
>   with this behavior (but implemented in C) would be a good addition to
>   the language. It looks like it wouldn't be hard to implement. **It could
>   be a builtin named `defaultdict`**. The first, required, argument to the
>   constructor should be the default value. Remaining arguments (even
>   keyword args) are passed unchanged to the dict constructor.

Discussion quickly moved from `defaultdict` being a built-in to it being part of the `collections` module, but the all-lowercase name stuck. This discussion took place back in 2006, so PEP 8 had been around for many years by then. Not sure why it never occurred to anyone that it should be named `DefaultDict` at the time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Google internal type was implemented in Python, so it would use the Python naming convention.

Comment: @user2357112 In the same thread where `OrderedDict` was being discussed, [Guido said this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-March/086639.html) in response to similar suggestion (that classes implemented in C should be named in all lowercase): *"Then they're all wrong. In 3.0 we're moving away from this, e.g.
cPickle is gone, so is cStringIO. **The implementation language should
not shine through**. \*Maybe\* the "built-in status" should guide the
capitalization, so only built-in types are lowercase (str, int, dict
etc.)."*