# Why Python naming is not following PEP and is inconsistent?

Tags: python

Why Python library naming is not following PEP and is inconsistent?

For example `defaultdict`, `OrderedDict`, both are classes, but one is `thelowercase` one is `TheCamelcase`.

```
import inspect
inspect.isclass(OrderedDict)
> True
inspect.isclass(defaultdict)
> True
```

Also why not `default_dict`, `heap_pop`? According to PEP, only class is `TheCamelcase` and all functions should be `the_underscore`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25597121/3346095

Comment: [`defaultdict` is not a function.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)